How to get rid of excess padding around image grid
I'm new to CSS. I made a 3x3 image grid using flex. Is there a way to get rid of padding around the images that are along the edges? I added a screenshot to explain what I mean. I can think of one way and it's to add specific classes to certain images to make it so either padding-left or padding-right = 0 but I have a feeling there's a better way to achieve this.


.wrapper--gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: $alabaster;
  @include tablet {
    padding: 0 2.25rem 1.75rem 2.25rem;
  }
}

.gallery__img-list {
  @include tablet {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.gallery__img {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  @include tablet {
    width: 33%; // get to 3 columns 
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
}
<section class="wrapper--gallery">
  <h2 class="gallery__title">Photo Gallery</h2>
  <ul class="gallery__img-list">
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-1.jpg" alt="crowd with raised hands at a concert, backlit with vibrant pink stage lights"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-2.jpg" alt="silhouette of a woman dancing energetically on stage under green and blue lights"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-3.jpg" alt="concert crowd raising their hands under a wash of pink stage lighting"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-4.jpg" alt="woman at a concert dancing with excitement, spotlighted by white stage beams"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-5.jpg" alt="energetic concert with crowd and fireworks display under purple lighting"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-6.jpg" alt="woman reaching out passionately at a concert with sparkling white lights and fog"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-7.jpg" alt="colorful concert with large crowd, vibrant lights and lasers illuminating the stage"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-8.jpg" alt="close-up of a dj's hands adjusting controls on a turntable under ambient lighting"></li>
    <li class="gallery__img"><img src="assets/images/Photo-gallery-9.jpg" alt="wide shot of a concert crowd with hands up, confetti falling under blue lighting"></li>
  </ul>
</section>





Do you really need flexbox for this? Grid would be a better option

ul has default margin and padding in browser link. You can set ul{padding:0;margin:0;}

AFAIK, there's no @include rule in CSS. Are you sure this isn't SCSS or LESS?

Update: never mind, display:grid is the easiest way.
Added this to the CSS to remove padding along the edges
.gallery__img:nth-child(3n+1) {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .gallery__img:nth-child(3n) {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    .gallery__img:nth-child(-n+3) {
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    .gallery__img:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

